# JS | My sticky menu is not showing when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

OK, LovableCodeGuy here, new to the JS world, although I doubt I'll be sticking to it long. I have a circular menu that is supposed to smoothly slide down into position `onscroll` by manipulating the `top` CSS attribute - going from `top: -100px;` when at the top of the page (out of sight) to `top: 400px;` when the user scrolls down with a `transition: 0.5s;`.

Pretty neat stuff.

Except it isn't, because I'm getting nothing in the way of JS functionality, but everything else is just peachy. The `JS` coding is inserted into the HTML document in between `<script></script>` & is placed above the `div` tags.

So I'll post the code down below and see if anyone can tell me what I am missing:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > 100) {
      $(".stickyMenu").addClass("scroll_reveal");
    } else {
      $(".stickyMenu").removeClass("scroll_reveal");
    }

  });
```

```css
.stickyMenu{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: #0D0155;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    z-index: 9999999;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.scroll_reveal{
    transition: 0.5s;
    top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <div class="stickyMenu">Menu</div>
    
    
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
        
    Text  Text<br><br>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see nothing when I run your code, try running the snippet in question...

Comment: Exactly, that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollTop is actually scroll
so just change the variable

```
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scrollTop > 100) {
```

so should be

```
if (scroll > 100) {
```

By the way, when writing JS/CSS/HTML try to work with Dev Tools ON.
those kind of errors would be there. you could easily fix it :)